# I'm able to run the code with zero observation, although the dataset has information pertaining to the filter that am using

Tags: r, dplyr

Eg:

```
Date<-filter(storedata, "Order Date">= "6/9/2014" & "Order Date"<="11/8/2016")
Shipmode<-filter(storedata, "Ship Mode" == "Standard Class")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need to see a sample of your dataset.  From the code you posted, I suspect the problem is with your `Order Date` column.  You're comparing it to a character string rather than a `Date` or `datetime`.  That's likely to be *very* problematic...

Comment: Thanks....Here's the sample data                                                                                    Order ID             Order Date     Ship Date Ship Mode Customer ID         Name 
CA-2016-152156 11/8/2016 11/11/2016 Second Class CG-12520 Claire 
CA-2016-152156 11/8/2016 11/11/2016 Second Class CG-12520 Claire

Comment: I figured out that the column names had space in it which I corrected using stringr...will work on the date format...thanks